# C# Windows Service does not execute code, however if I create a thread on a form everything runs fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I am currently working on a software that is made up of a Windows form to control the configuration and a Windows Service that runs in the background to process data.

The Windows Service creates a thread and calls it OnStart, however the thread never starts. However if I move this code into the Windows Form and have the thread start on a button press runs flawlessly. I'm installing my Service with Account User and logging in with an admin user.

I would love to know peoples thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here.

```
public partial class ProgramName : ServiceBase
{
    private int _heartBeatInterval = 1;
    private settingConfigManager settings;
    private Thread _thread_ProgramName = null;
    public ProgramName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        settings = new settingConfigManager();

        // set the thread
        _thread_ProgramName = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProgramName_Start));
        _thread_ProgramName.Name = "ProgramName Main";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _thread_ProgramName.Start();
        }
        catch (ThreadStateException stateEx)
        {
            Logging.LogServiceException("ThreadStateException", stateEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException memEx)
        {
            Logging.LogServiceException("OutOfMemoryException", memEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.LogServiceException("Exception", ex.ToString());
        }
    }



private void ProgramName_Start()
    {
        // Loop infintely
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                settings.LoadConfig();
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(settings.Config.m_nextProcessDate) < DateTime.Now || settings.Config.m_nextProcessDate == "")
                {
                    // Start the service
                    ProgramName_RunExport();
                }

                if (settings.Config.m_settingToggleSFTPDownload == "True" & settings.Config.m_settingToggleDataImport == "True")
                {
                    ProgramName_Download();
                }


                if (settings.Config.m_isUpdateAvailable == "True")
                {
                    //Load update class
                    //Install new updates
                    ProgramName_Update();
                }


                // wait (1 minute -default)
                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, _heartBeatInterval, 0));
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException outofrangeEx)
            {
                Logging.LogServiceException("ArgumentOutOfRangeException", outofrangeEx.ToString());
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException abortEx)
            {
                Logging.LogServiceException("ThreadAbortException", abortEx.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LogServiceException("Exception", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure OnStart is being called?

Comment: not likely your problem but sleeping a thread in a `while(true)` is kind of an anti-pattern. The better way to do it is start a timer in `OnStart` that is non repeating, then at the end of the timer set the next interval to be one minute.

Comment: Also, please show us the `Main` method when it is running as a service. And how did you know the thread was not started? If you put a `Debugger.Launch()` inside the OnStart does it get reached? What about if you put it in `ProgramName_Start()`?

Comment: How are you sure the thread isn't starting? Does it start when you run in debug mode?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I appreciate the advice and I will test that idea once I get my service functioning properly. It definitely sounds like a better idea.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I honestly didn't think about attaching the debugger in the _Start() function and it is reaching there. I'm guessing MAYBE this is a permissions issue? I am installing the service with the below account which is an admin. http://i.imgur.com/ii8K6sb.png    The program writes / reads from \AppData\Local\

Comment: @eknofsky I would double check that the service is actually running as that user. Also, depending on how you are finding `\AppData\Local\ ` I know some times that can act funny with services.